# Delete lines of text until new blank line reached

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I'm looking for a way of removing all text in a file up until a new blank line is reached.  For example:

```
Line 1
Line 2

Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Should end up looking like:

```
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, how about multiple new lines? you have multiple new lines in your file? if yes then please post expected output as per that example also in your post.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` and test for 0 fields. (it will also work if line has just spaces or tab, count as blank)

```
awk 't;NF==0 {t=1}' file
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

`t;` print line if its true

`NF==0` test for number of fields=0

If 0 fields, set `t=1`

Can be shorten some:

```
awk 't;!NF{t=1}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '0,/^$/d' file
```

Delete all lines from line 1 until an empty line. This is GNU specific n.b. `1,/^$/d` fill not include line 1 and so if line 1 were empty and the remainder of the file had non-empty lines, the whole of the file would be deleted.

Alternative, for all seds:

```
sed -n '/^$/{:a;n;p;ba}' file
```

Turn off automatic printing `-n` option. Only print lines following the first empty line to the end of file.